# Athena Prepared Statement Parameter Order

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, prepared-statement, amazon-athena, presto

I'm attempting to use the [Athena parameterized queries feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html) in conjunctions with CTEs.

If I run a simple Athena CTE select statement like this, I get back no results even though I should get a single row back with a single value of `1`:

```bash
aws athena start-query-execution  \
  --query-string "WITH cte as (select 1 where 1 = ?) select * from cte where 2 = ?" \
  --query-execution-context "Database"="default"  \
  --result-configuration "OutputLocation"="s3://athena-test-bucket/" \
  --execution-parameters "1" "2"

# Output CSV:
# "_col0"
```

Strangely, if I reverse the parameters, the query works correctly:

```bash
aws athena start-query-execution  \
  --query-string "WITH cte as (select 1 where 1 = ?) select * from cte where 2 = ?" \
  --query-execution-context "Database"="default"  \
  --result-configuration "OutputLocation"="s3://athena-test-bucket/" \
  --execution-parameters "2" "1"

# Output CSV:
# "_col0"
# "1"
```

The [AWS docs state that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html):

> In parameterized queries, parameters are positional and are denoted by ?. Parameters are assigned values by their order in the query. Named parameters are not supported.

But this clearly doesn't seem to be the case, as the query only acts as expected when the parameters are in reversed order.

How can I get Athena to correctly insert parameters in the standard, first-to-last, positional way that's typical of other DBs? While the above example is simple, in reality, I have queries with arbitrarily nested CTEs with arbitrary amounts of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue (incorrect parameters order for prepared statements using `WITH` clause) in old versions of Presto ([link 1](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/17012), [link 2](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/16347)) and Trino ([link](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/1191)) which was fixed. For Presto in version [0.272](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.272.html) ([fix PR](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/17083)):

> Fix parameter ordering for prepared statement queries using a WITH clause.

Sadly at the moment of writing Athena engine version 2 is based on [Presto 0.217](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html) so you need to workaround by changing the parameters order.

**UPD**

Should work in Athena v3 engine, which is based on Trino.

Comment: This is great info, thanks! Do you happen to know how often Amazon tends to update the underlying version of Presto? Guessing it's pretty infrequent...

Comment: @JKillian TBH no idea. They just relatively recently updated to Athena v2 engine which is the 0.217 version of Presto.

Comment: Athena Engine v3 is now out, it appears to be based on Trinio and the bug mentioned in my original question seems to now be resolved. So this issue should only affect people still using v2.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html